# Composite musical notes

Tags: sound

I want to be able to define my own musical notes from the ones provided by Mathematica (just as I can define my own data types using standard ones in C programming language). For example, I want to be able to use this as a musical note (call it "E[Flat]F" =  Gamaka["E[Flat]", "F"]) where

```
Gamaka[X_, Y_] := Sound[{SoundNote[ X, 0.15, "Violin"], SoundNote[ Y, 0.02, "Violin"], 
SoundNote[ X, 0.15, "Violin"]}]
```

But I am not sure how to use this to generate sound such as

```
Sound[SoundNote[{"CG", "GF", "EC"}, 1, "Violin"]]
```

where "CG" = Gamaka["C","G"] etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? It will split the strings and even allow for sharps/flats and numbers.

```
Gamaka[{X_, Y_}, voice_] := {
  SoundNote[X, 0.15, voice],
  SoundNote[Y, 0.02, voice],
  SoundNote[X, 0.15, voice]}
GamakaSeq[notes_, voice_] := Gamaka[
    StringCases[#, RegularExpression["([A-G][#\[Flat]b]?\\d*)"]]
    , voice] & /@ notes

Sound[
 GamakaSeq[{"CG", "G#F", "EC", "CG", "GF", "C4C4"}, "Violin"]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Flinty, I will work with this. Though I feel Mathematica should make this more formal the way C programming language has made the definition of new data types formal.

Comment: Yeah - or OO like e.g Sound takes objects with a note interface 'Soundable'. There are other places where I don't like how Mathematica uses strings e.g integration and classify methods, but I suppose it's easier for the developers that way.